# How to hide action name on URL and replace by a fictitious one?

Tags: yii

```
'urlManager'=>array(
   'urlFormat'=>'path',
   'rules'=>array(
     'gii'=>'gii',
     'gii/<controller:\w+>'=>'gii/<controller>',
     'gii/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'gii/<controller>/<action>',
     '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<param:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
     '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
     '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
     '<controller:\w+>'=>'<controller>/index',
    ),
    'showScriptName'=>false,
```

Those are the rules I have applied.

If I do:

```
http://something.dev/experience/listByColor/Red
```

I get all experiences with color Red.

```
actionListByColor($color);
```

This works.

I wish the same to work when the user does:

```
http://something.dev/experience/color/Red
```

I've tried those rules:

```
'experience/color/'=>'experience/listByColor/'
```

But I always get:

> System couldn't found the requested action "color".

How can I make this work?

It seems that urlFormat is NOT fit for this, because it seems to expect a valid path on the left side of `=>` and, on this case, we haven't any valid path there.

No other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the params/id part. Use the appropriate rule below:

```
'experience/color/<param:\w+>'=>'experience/listByColor/'
'experience/color/<id:\d+>'=>'experience/listByColor/'
'experience/color/<color>'=>'experience/listByColor/'
```

Comment: That's well spotted. The first rule did it. Care to drop a few lines about the last one? <color> that does it mean on that context? Thanks.